# Is it possible to "configure SCM repositories" in xCode from the commandline?

Tags: xcode, version-control

I'm developing a sweet app, so of course I'm using version control. The problem is, I'm a student and I move from computer to computer in the library. I wrote a script to copy my svn config file over from my personal storage on the network, but I still have to manually "configure SCM" every time I start working on my sweet app. What I mean is, I have to let xCode know about the repo every time. This means opening up a browser, going to assembla, and copy-pasting the URL... all stuff I'd rather do by running a sweet script.

So I'm wondering: when I "configure SCM" in xcode, where are those configurations being kept? Would it be difficult to automate that setup?

Thanks!

update: this is not a solution, but I added a line to the end of my script that at least copies the URL to clipboard for me. That makes my life easier, but I'd still rather automate the process by editing some xCode config file, or proj file or something.

z.

Comment: As an aside, if yo move from site to site, you should use a *distributed* version control system (DVCS) like [Git](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info) or [Mercurial](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mercurial/info). Those are *really*, err..., "sweet", I guess ;) Assembla supports Git. [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) supports both (even with *private* projects, and for free)

Comment: Normally I use git, but this time I'm using SVN.